# libgdx - find the coordinates different from the point of origin?

Tags: android, libgdx, coordinates, sprite

I 'd like someone to advise me a way to find the coordinates of a point on a sprite in libgdx .

[image]

As you can see from the image I have set the sprite with the point of origin on the red dot , and I can not change it.
I would leave the red dot as the source and find the coordinates of the green on the same sprite .

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public void create () {

    img = new Texture("rocket.png");
    font = new BitmapFont();
    font.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);

    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    sprite = new Sprite(img);

    spacesprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("space.jpg")));
    spacesprite.setPosition(0,0);
    spacesprite.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    point = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("point.png")));


    batch = new SpriteBatch();

}

@Override
public void render () {

    sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - sprite.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - sprite.getHeight()/2);
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);

    point.setPosition(sprite.getX() + sprite.getWidth()/2 - point.getWidth()/2, sprite.getY() + sprite.getHeight()/2);
    point.setOrigin(point.getWidth()/2, 0);

    if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
        //sprite.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX() - sprite.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY() - sprite.getHeight()/2);
        if(Gdx.input.getX() < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2)
        {
            //System.out.println("x: " + Gdx.input.getX() + " - y: " + Gdx.input.getY());
            sprite.setRotation(rotation++);
            point.setRotation(rotation++);
            System.out.println("Sprite: X" + sprite.getX() + " - Y:" + sprite.getY());
        }
        else
        {
            //System.out.println("x: " + Gdx.input.getX() + " - y: " + Gdx.input.getY());
            sprite.setRotation(rotation--);
            point.setRotation(rotation--);
            System.out.println("Sprite: X" + sprite.getX() + " - Y:" + sprite.getY());
        }
    }

    batch.begin();
    spacesprite.draw(batch);
    sprite.draw(batch);
    point.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

someone can adapt the code , when I rotate I'd get the position , but they are insecure about my implementation .

Comment: Reading your comment, it sounds like you know where the green spot is and you want to know where it is after a rotation around the origin, right?

Comment: Is exactly what I do .

Comment: sprite.setRotation(rotation++);
point.setRotation(rotation++);
This probably does not do what you intend it too do. The first sprite gets rotated 1 degree less than the second sprite, because after the first operation the rotation is incremented. where as for the second operation the first incremented rotation is used (and then incremented again)

Comment: you have no idea how I could do?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a middle point on the rectangular sprite, try something like this:

```
float x = obj.getOriginX() + obj.getHeight();
float y = obj.getOriginY() + obj.getWidth() / 2;
```

Comment: Thanks but maybe I explained bad, the object rotates around the origin , so I need to know where the green dot so that it becomes a vector.
With your method X and Y are always fixed .
Tips ?

Answer (score 0):

Either use Gonio, matrix or quaternions to calculate the rotated coordinates.

For a few simple calculations I'd use gonio, something like:

```
float angle_rad = sprite.getRotation() / 180.0f * PI;

float rotated_x = Math.sin(angle_rad) * y + Math.cos(angle_rad) * x;
float rotated_y = Math.sin(angle_rad) * x + Math.cos(angle_rad) * y;
```

If you have to do this more often look into matrices or quaternions, matrices are a little easier though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: i have edit the code but i'm not sure for the solution